# React Redux ,how to synchronize?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I Have the redux connected in my code

```
   loginAction(){
    console.log("dashboard login action");
    this.props.login("username","password")
    console.log("mapstate to props dashboard "+JSON.stringify(
        this.props.loginStatus));
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    loginStatus:state.loginStatus
    
};
```

}

when I try to access this.props.loginStatus after calling the this.props.login("username","password") method,this becomes undefined. When i observed it is because it takes time to update the store. How to figure out when the store update is done by a callback or something,when the store updated i can get the this.props.loginStatus

```
export default function LoginReducer(state = initialstate, action) {
console.log("loginreducer calling =" + action.type + " " + JSON.stringify(
    action.payload));
switch (action.type) {

    case "USER_LOGIN":
        console.log("case USER_LOGIN");
        //axiox get auth url
        return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
    default:
        return state

}
```

}

attached is my reducer

Comment: Can we have the rest of the code please, we need to know where you are accessing this store

Comment: sure already added

Comment: Please note that you aren't waiting for the login action to complete, please check async await or add Promise response if you are using it inside this.props.login() already

Comment: Hasan Riza could you show me an example , basically it should happen from the reducer